# Storing return value of a function in a variable not working

Tags: javascript

I playing around with something like this

```js
function myFunc(){
    var val = 10;
    new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
    setTimeout(function(){
        //
      val = 20;
      resolve();
    },1000)
  }).then(function(){
    return val;
  })
}

var val = myFunc();
console.log(val);
```

Here I'm expecting `20` in output but getting `undefined`. What's wrong here ?

Fiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/nvLc60bm/

Comment: Problems: 1. `myFunc` doesn't return anything. 2. Returning `val` from the callback function of `then` method does not make it a return value of the outer function. 3. If you return the promise from the `myFunc` function, you need to either `await` or chain a `then` method to the `myFunc` function call.

Comment: can you play around it here https://jsfiddle.net/nvLc60bm/ ?

Comment: [Try this code](https://pastebin.com/LxjD2TSs)